# Python Turtle Error In Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So i made a python turtle thing a while ago and it worked just fine. However, when i try to run it now it doesnt work. Here is the code:

```
import turtle
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(144)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(144)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(144)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(144)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

It gives a error saying:

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'
File "C:\Users\melek büyük\Desktop\Programlama\Python\ptrh.py", line 2, in 
turtle.forward(100)"

It didn't do this before. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Don't you need to create an object and call methods on that object? (I've never used python-turtle, btw, I've only used it in LOGO way back when python wasn't a thing yet)

Comment: Yes you need to create a turtle before it can move. Please check with one of the many turtle tutorials available on the web.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle seems to indicate otherwise. I tested on my computer and your code works fine. You've probably created a file called `turtle.py` in your working directory that hides the builtin `turtle` module. Renaming the file should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your file might be called turtle or you have another file called turtle. This would cause the import to not actual import the turtle library, so you should rename the file.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you forgot to initialize a new object like this:

```
import turtle

your_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

# And then you can start drawing

your_turtle.forward(100)
your_turtle.right(144)
your_turtle.forward(100)
your_turtle.right(144)
your_turtle.forward(100)

# ...
```

Comment: Also you don't actually need to initialize an object, according to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#module-turtle